# MVC: How can I use two different properties for url and display link in DisplayTemplate custom Url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a DisplayTemplate folder within shared folder which has a Url view that looks like this:

```
 <a href="@ViewData.Model" target="_blank"> @ViewData.Model</a>
```

This is what properties in my class looks like:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        public string WebsiteName { get; set; }  //i want this as display text of link          

        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
         public string website { get; set; } //this should be the url to which user will be redirected to          

    }
```

I am aware that I can do it in other ways but I want to do it using the DisplayTemplate if possible.

Comment: Have you declared your model in the view, like @model ViewModel? Once you have done it you create your link like <a href="@model.Websitename" target="_blank"> @model.websitel</a>

Comment: @model MvcDemo.Models.Employee

Comment: @Kami I know I can do it like that. Like I said in my question I want to do it using DIsplayTemplate.

Comment: @Arbaaz Are you familiar with how DisplayTemplates work? You can create your own for your specific model and then put Razor code in it as Kamil described.

Comment: @JasonlPrice I am learning mvc and I misunderstood what kami was saying. I thought he is referring to the view which has `@Html.DisplayForModel()`

Answer (score 0):

In your DisplayTemplate place the following at the top of the file.

```
@model Employee
```

Once you've done that, you have access to its properties.
So you can do

```
<a href="@Model.website" target="_blank"> @Model.WebsiteName</a>
```

Comment: Oh, Did you edit you comment? When I first looked there was no code example.

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MvcDemo.Models.Employee'.

Comment: Yes, I did it shortly after I commented.

Comment: @Kami I thought you were talking about the view which has `@Html.DisplayForModel()` . My mistake.

Comment: @Arbaaz I think you're making this more difficult than it should be. Just create Employee.cshtml in the DisplayTemplates folder, add this code, and MVC will do the rest.

Comment: @JasonlPrice   I Created Employee.cshtml in the DisplayTemplates folder but its not giving me the rest of the properties such as phonenumber etc. (i have omitted other properties in the example that i gave) . I am expecting `@Html.DisplayForModel()` to produce labels for each property and url for the one i have marked as url in annotations. The url markup must be taken from DisplayTemplates. You are probably right that i am making it more difficult that it should be , its just that I am exploring possibilities right now.

Comment: Can you edit your post and show what you have in your DisplayTemplate and I your model? Even in the DisplayTemplate you should have access to @Html.DisplayForModel()

Answer (score 0):

If your Employee.cshtml is in partial view, you really won't be able to access your properties such as phonenumber etc. You'll only be able to access those properties on your main page, but not on partial view. On your partial view you may only access the properties of its model.

The answer of JasonIPrice is technically correct.
P.S. I can't comment on your answer JasonlPrice.